# No Mouse Support in NTVDM in Windows 10 32 bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, ntvdm

I am trying to run QBasic in my 32 bit installation of windows 10. Qbasic runs just fine, but there is no mouse support. In Windows 7 32 bit , there was mouse support for QBasic, it is not present in windows 10 32bit.

Can it be somehow enabled?

P.S: I tried turning legacy console on, but there it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: better use [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1.), it also runs on 64bit Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i have figured it out. It was caused by the new quick edit mode introduced in windows 10.

Open the dos program you want to open.
The right click on title bar.
Then click on properties.
Then untick the Quick edit mode checkbox.
Apply the settings.

Now your dos application should be taking mouse input.